# Fibonacci generator with user request

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create Fibonacci generator. Maybe smb can explain to me how I can start creating sequence not from zero, but start point will be by user request (for example number 5 in the sequence) and can go forward and back (in minus as well). The amount of showing numbers also should be by user request.

```
function* fibonacci(number) {

let previous_first = 0, previous_second = 1, next = 1;

while(true) {
    next = previous_first + previous_second;
    previous_first = previous_second;
    previous_second = next;

    yield next;
   }
};
```

Comment: Just store them all in an array. It takes only 80 values untill the values get too big to be represented by numbers in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like below would give the results:

```js
function getFibonnaciSequence(firstNum, secondNum, sequenceCount) {
    let sum = 0;
    let squenceArray = [];
    while(sequenceCount != 0) {
    sum = firstNum + secondNum;
    squenceArray.push(sum);
    firstNum = secondNum;
    secondNum = sum;
    sequenceCount--;
  }
    return squenceArray; 
}

console.log(getFibonnaciSequence(2,5, 10));
```

Comment: Hi, could you explain what you've changed from OP's code ?